# Convert 404/500 or any other error code to 301

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

I have site in Mvc and i want that any URL with error code 404 will redirect to 301.
Where i can do this permanently(Web.Config/IIS) and how?
Please suggest me the option keeping in mind the SEO part of a site.

I have hundreds of Urls generating 404 and 500 errors i want to redirect them to site base url "www.site.com"

I have error links like this:
www.site.com/index.php?page=item&id=39

www.site.com/Ad/Detail/b7bd026f-3ba2-444f-8786-6e551d6e1668

Comment: Sounds like you want [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). This isn't strictly part of MVC, but it is very well purposed for 301 redirecting URLs to another place.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of url rewriting in this case, because i have hundreds of Urls generating 404 and 500 errors i want to redirect them to site base url "www.site.com"
i have error links like this:
www.site.com/index.php?page=item&id=39

www.site.com/Ad/Detail/b7bd026f-3ba2-444f-8786-6e551d6e1668